# Searching for a better term for fulfilling a request for money?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I'm looking for better wording in a translation for an App where you can *send* and *receive* money as well as *request* and *pay* it.
So under transactions, there are 4 categories: money sent, money received, money requested and money paid (meaning fulfilled requests).
I think that "paying" could be confused with sending money.

Also, I'm thinking of splitting the 4 categories into *in* and *out*.
 [image: Table of categories]

What do you think? Any ideas for better wording?

I'm not a native speaker.

**P.S:** I know this intersects with UX, if you think it would be better suited there feel free to let me know.

Comment: Do you have ambiguity between 'sent' and 'paid'? I think your table of categorization is good enough.

Comment: I don't get the distinction at all. From the payer's perspective, any and all money sent is money paid. You have fulfilled the request immediately. If I request money from you, and you send it over, you have spent that money that very second. It has been paid. No two ways about it. Whether or not I have received it, or acknowledged receiving it, is irrelevant. It has been paid.

Comment: Thanks @BiscuitBoy, if nothing better comes up I will use it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I don't quite understand what you mean, sorry. Money *sent* is not *requested* by the other user, you can send it without anybody requesting it, and when it's "send" as a reaction to a request, I call it *paying*.

Comment: You could use *Charged* in place of *Paid*. It's beyond the scope of your question, but it might actually be better to change your other term—instead of just *Sent* (which happens with all transactions) you could use *Gifted* or similar. You could also make your sub-categories match on both sides, for example "Received-Invoiced & Received-Grant; Sent-Invoiced & Sent-Grant" where *Invoiced* means "in response to a request" and *Grant* means "without a prior request". (Also, I don't necessarily think this question is off-topic here, but you might get better/different answers at UX.)

Comment: I'm gonna stick with sending, since it's an integral part of the app, but charging instead of requesting does sound better. If you make that an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: I'm with Reg over "sent" and "paid" and there, you might use "called" in place of "paid". You might even use "requested" again but that would be very confusing unless your table layout was very clear.

Even if I hadn't worked in the money transfer business, I'd be quite sure that "charged" is a lot worse, not at all better than "requested".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Charged** would be a possible alternative term for your scheme:

> **charge** *verb*
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Demand (an amount) as a price from someone for a service rendered or
>      goods supplied. *‘the restaurant charged $15 for dinner’* [WITH TWO
>      OBJECTS] *‘he charged me 2 euros for the postcard’* [NO OBJECT]
>      *‘museums should charge for admission’*
>
>    1. 1 Record the cost of something as an amount payable by (someone) or on (an account) *‘they charge the calls to their credit-card accounts’*

([Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/charge))

This could potentially replace either *Requested* or *Paid*.

One other possible alternative term would be **Billed**, which is a near-synonym for *charged* (See [Oxford **bill** *verb*, definition 2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/bill)).

I think there is a stronger implication with *charged* that the money has actually changed hands, whereas with *billed* it sounds more like the request has been made but the money has not yet been handed over, so overall I would prefer *charged* for your purposes.

---

[Aside: Unfortunately, I think there's going to be some ambiguity for any scheme that relies on single words, since virtually all of these terms could be from the point of view of either pay-er or pay-ee. There is also be some ambiguity between outstanding requests (requests that have been made but not yet honored) and settled requests for the above suggestions.

Is it possible to use multi-word categories? Something like Money Sent, Money Sent-on-Request, Money Received, and Money Received-on-Request would be more clearly understandable, I think.]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

It would clearer if you gave the two parties different names instead of referring to both as *users*, e.g., you could call the one on the "in" side "Party A" and the one on "out" side "Party B". Note: For simplicity, in what follows, I consider Party B to be singular rather than plural, but that implies no loss of generality.

If you did that:

- For *requested* you could say, "Money requested by Party A and
  fulfilled by Party B".
- For *received* you could say, "Money received by Party A from Party
  B".
- For *sent*, you could say, "Money sent by Party A to Party B".
- For *paid*, you could say, "Money paid by Party A to Party B".

There appears to be an obvious issue with the wording of the *requested* element. It seems to me that it should read "Money requested by Party A from Party B" rather than "Money requested by Party A and fulfilled by Party B" ... because "fulfilled* in this context implies *received*.